# How do I make a graph with branching rectangular edges, labeled before branching?

Tags: tikz-node, tikz-graphs, edge

This graph duplicates the label, and the edges are not vertical or horizontal. I would like a vertical edge to leave A, labeled 'x' then split into two right and left horizontal branches which would turn 90 deg toward nodes B and C.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {graphs, graphdrawing, quotes}
\usegdlibrary{layered}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \graph [
            layered layout,
            nodes = {draw, fill = white},
            edge quotes = {fill = white},
            level distance = 3 cm,
            sibling sep = 4 cm
        ]{
            A -> ["x", out = -90, in = 90] {
                B,
                C
           }
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: What I'd like to see]

Comment: The reason your `edge` is not a straight line is the `in=` `out`=` syntax. It causes the lines to fit to the entry and exit angles and in between will bend to the most logical bent shape, in your case an S-shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you insist using `\graph` depending on your usecase, you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {positioning, calc}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2.5cm,>=stealth]
            \node[rectangle,inner sep=2pt,draw,align=center] (A) {A};
            \node[rectangle,inner sep=2pt,draw,align=center,below left = of A] (B) {B};
            \node[rectangle,inner sep=2pt,draw,align=center,below right = of A] (C) {C};
            \coordinate (D) at ($(A)!.7!(A |- B)$);
            \draw[thick,->] (A) -- (D) node[anchor=west,midway] {x} -| (B);
            \draw[thick,->] (D) -| (C);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Or something slightly more simple like:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {positioning, calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2.5cm,>=stealth]
        \node[rectangle,inner sep=2pt,draw,align=center] (A) {A};
        \node[rectangle,inner sep=2pt,draw,align=center,below left = of A] (B) {B};
        \node[rectangle,inner sep=2pt,draw,align=center,below right = of A] (C) {C};
        \draw[thick,->] (A) -- ($(B)!.5!(C)$) edge (C) node[anchor=west,midway] {x}  -- (B) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT2**: So, if you want to use `\graph`, you could use this, alhtough the labeling is a bit awkward:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {graphs, graphdrawing, quotes}
\usegdlibrary{layered}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,thick,
        connect/.style={to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}},
        connectwlabel/.style={to path={|- node[pos=0.25,anchor=west]{x} (\tikztotarget)}},
        ]
        \graph [
        layered layout,
        nodes = {draw, fill = white, minimum width=.5cm, minimum height=.5cm, thick},
        edge quotes = {fill = white},
        level distance = 3cm,
        sibling sep = 4cm,
        ]{
            A ->[connectwlabel] B;      
            A ->[connect] C;
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT3**: It turns out, you can actually combine the approaches and do this:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing, quotes,calc}
\usegdlibrary{layered}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,thick,
        connect/.style={to path={(\tikztostart) -- ($(\tikztostart)!.7!(\tikztostart |- \tikztotarget)$) -| (\tikztotarget)}},
        connectwlabel/.style={to path={(\tikztostart) -- node[pos=0.5,anchor=west]{x} ($(\tikztostart)!.7!(\tikztostart |- \tikztotarget)$) -|  (\tikztotarget)}},
        ]
        \graph [
        layered layout,
        nodes = {draw, fill = white, minimum width=.5cm, minimum height=.5cm, thick},
        edge quotes = {fill = white},
        level distance = 2.5cm,
        sibling sep = 2cm,
        ]{
            A ->[connectwlabel] B;      
            A ->[connect] C;
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which (with some adjustments to the `level distance` and `sibling sep`) looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I would like to use ```\graph```.My MWE is extracted from a large graph for which the tikz graph drawing tools are helpful. The solution proposed would be unwieldy in that context.

Comment: That makes sense, I added a version of the code using graph.

Comment: The first version is close to ideal. I edited my question to show what would be ideal. The example  using graph makes an already wide graph wider.

Comment: Ok, I gave it one more try. I'm afraid that is as close as I'm going to get with my current knowledge of `\graph`.

Comment: This works, except that the ```x``` is hard-wired. Is it possible to make the contents of the label variable? Regarding the position of the label, I find the result more appealing if ```anchor=west]{x}``` is replaced with ```fill = white]{x}```