# level distance not working consistently

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, graphs

The present question is a continuation of [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/604537/how-do-i-make-a-graph-with-branching-rectangular-edges-labeled-before-branching), and relies on answers given there. Here is the code that generates the image below.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {calc, graphs, graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary {trees}
\usegdlibrary{layered}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    > = stealth,
    every node/.append style = {font = \sf\vphantom{gf}},
    connect/.style = {to path = {(\tikztostart) -- ($(\tikztostart)!.5!(\tikztostart |- \tikztotarget)$) -| (\tikztotarget)}},
    connectEffects/.style = {to path = {(\tikztostart) -- node[pos = 0.5, fill = white]{effects} ($(\tikztostart)!.65!(\tikztostart |- \tikztotarget)$) -|  (\tikztotarget)}},
    connectSubjects/.style = {to path = {(\tikztostart) -- node[pos = 0.5, fill = white]{subjects} ($(\tikztostart)!.65!(\tikztostart |- \tikztotarget)$) -|  (\tikztotarget)}},
    connectFactors/.style = {to path = {(\tikztostart) -- node[pos = 0.5, fill = white]{block factors} ($(\tikztostart)!.65!(\tikztostart |- \tikztotarget)$) -|  (\tikztotarget)}},
    connectSize/.style = {to path = {(\tikztostart) -- node[pos = 0.5, fill = white]{block size} ($(\tikztostart)!.65!(\tikztostart |- \tikztotarget)$) -|  (\tikztotarget)}},
]

\graph [
layered layout,
nodes = {draw, fill = white},
edge quotes = {fill = white},
level 1/.style = {level distance = 1.5 cm},
level 2/.style = {level distance = 1.5 cm},
level 3/.style = {level distance = 1.5 cm},
level 4/.style = {level distance = 1.5 cm},
level 5/.style = {level distance = 0.75 cm},
level 6/.style = {level distance = 0.75 cm},
level 7/.style = {level distance = 0.75 cm},
level 8/.style = {level distance = 0.75 cm},
sibling distance = 2 cm
]{
    experiment ->[connectEffects] {
        fixed ->[connectSubjects] {
          homogeneous -> [minimum layers = 4]
                CRD ->
                    CRFD -> 
                            CRSP,
            heterogeneous ->[connectFactors] {
                one ->[connectSize] {
                    large -> {
                        RCB -> 
                            GCB ->
                                RCBF ->
                                    RBSP
                    },
                    small ->
                        PBIB or BTIB -> 
                            BIB
                },
                two -> [minimum layers = 2]
                    LSD
            }
        },
        mixed
   }
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I want to make the distance between levels 1.5 cm until level 5, and then switch to 0.75 cm. This seems to fail after level 6.

**A subsidiary question:** I would like to make the code that defines the four connectors `connectEffects/.style =` ... more general and concise.

[image: tree generated by the code above]